# Cancel readonly buttons "clicked animation"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to cancel the "clicked animation"  for readonly inputs (make them behave like disabled buttons, I don't use disabled buttons because I can style them for IE).

Maybe there is a way to set the css style for a submit/button when it's clicked (on mousedown).

I mean something similar to hover css:

```
input[readonly] { color: blue } 
input[readonly]:hover { color: red }
input[readonly]:mouseover { color: green }
```

I would prefer a css2-based solution or a javascript-based solution, rather than a css3 solution.

Thanks from advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
input[readonly]{ color: blue } 
input[readonly]:hover { color: red }
input[readonly]:active { color: green }
```

Answer (score 3):

hi use :active class this will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

The psuedo-class you're looking for is `:active`.

btw, IE10 supports arbitrary styling of disabled elements.